# how to write variable concatinated with string to a txt file using bat

Tags: batch-file

Is this code correct? I want to write the user input to a bat file concatenated to a string.

```
set file=C:\Users\Public\Documents\user.txt
set /p SomeVar=Please enter your identification?
echo Identification %SomeVar%>> %file%
```

Comment: this should be posted on Code Review.....

Comment: @SteveFest no, it really shouldn't. What help would CR give? They don't do "does this work" tests, and there's almost nothing _to_ review.

Comment: Code Review, or Peer Code Review, is the act of consciously and systematically convening with one's fellow programmers to check each other's code for errors.... (taken from Code Review site)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest making sure that there was some actual input to the variable request.

```bat
Set "file=C:\Users\Public\Documents\user.txt"
Set/P "SomeVar=Please enter your identification: "
If Not "%SomeVar%"=="" (
    >>"%file%" Echo=Identification %SomeVar%
)
```